# How can I prevent "window.location.replace()" from being overwritten?

Tags: javascript, html, function, object

I need a way to prevent `window.location.replace()` from being changed/overwritten (ex: `window.location.replace = function(){ return "Hi" }`. At first, I tried `Object.freeze(window.location.replace)` but this did not do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Object.defineProperty` to make it non-writable and non-configurable:

```js
'use strict';

Object.defineProperty(
  window.location,
  'replace',
  { value: window.location.replace }
);

// Throws in strict mode
window.location.replace = function(){ return "Hi" };

// In sloppy mode, the above assignment will fail silently
```

Answer (score 1):

2 things here:
_ `strict mode`: to allow `Object.freeze` to prevent Objects being edited. Without 'strict mode', `Object.freeze` can only prevent adding, deleting.
_ `Object.free` can only take effect for 1 level in the object.

So the solution is:

```
'use strict';
Object.freeze(window.location);
```